# Calculate sample size from margin of error and confidence level

Tags: sample-size

I need to calculate the sample size for the data I have. I am given a margin of error5% with a confidence level 95% .

Which formula can I use to get the sample size value if the total population size is X?
Sorry, I searched the internet but couldn't find a formula for this purpose.

https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/find-sample-size/#Cochran

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are estimating a binomial proportion near to $p\approx 1/2$ based on a sample of
size $n,$ then a 95% CI is of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$ for which the margin of error is
$$M = 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n} \approx 1.96\sqrt{(1/2)(1/2)/n}\\
= 1.96\sqrt{1/4n} \approx 1/\sqrt{n}.$$

So, if $M = 0.05 = 5\%.$ then $n \approx 1/M^2 = 1/(.05)^2 = 400.$

You do not give many details about the parameter being estimated or the kind of confidence being used. My computations above are based on estimating binomial
success probability $p \approx 1/2,$ as in some election polling situations. This is the only elementary application I know about where your information is sufficient.

If this is not the application you have in mind, then you will need to give more information: for example, the approximate value of $p$ for a binomial CI or an estimate of population variance $\sigma^2$ if you are trying to estimate the mean $\mu$ of a normal population. Other applications of confidence intervals may
require various additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Python implementation (not requiring any external libraries):

```
# https://github.com/shawnohare/samplesize/blob/master/samplesize.py

def sampleSize(population_size, margin_error=.05,confidence_level=.95,sigma=1/2):

    alpha = 1 - (confidence_level)
    zdict = {
        .90: 1.645,
        .91: 1.695,
        .99: 2.576,
        .97: 2.17,
        .94: 1.881,
        .93: 1.812,
        .95: 1.96,
        .98: 2.326,
        .96: 2.054,
        .92: 1.751
    }
    if confidence_level in zdict:
        z = zdict[confidence_level]
    else:
        from scipy.stats import norm
        z = norm.ppf(1 - (alpha/2))
    N = population_size
    M = margin_error
    numerator = z**2 * sigma**2 * (N / (N-1))
    denom = M**2 + ((z**2 * sigma**2)/(N-1))
    return int(numerator/denom + 0.5)

for population in [100,1000,10000,50000]:
    n = sampleSize(population)
    print("Population %d requires sample size of %d" % (population, n))
```

Result:

```
Population 100 requires sample size of 80
Population 1000 requires sample size of 278
Population 10000 requires sample size of 370
Population 50000 requires sample size of 381
```

Validated by checking: https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/sample-size-calculator/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).